# Multiple Activities and Up Button

Tags: android

I have an activity that can be asked to run after clicking buttons on many different activities and hence it does not have a "single parent".  Therefore in the android manifest I cannot define its parent so I cant get the "Up" button to function properly.

Is there a way I can have the "up" button return to the activity that called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass ComponentName of starting activity as an extra

```
intent = new Intent(this, UpButtonActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARENT_COMPONENT_NAME, new ComponentName(this, ThisActivity.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

The Activity with up button

```
private ComponentName parent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    parent = getIntent().getParcelable(EXTRA_PARENT_COMPONENT_NAME);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (parent != null) {
                final Intent parentIntent = new Intent();
                parentIntent.setComponentName(parent);
                startActivity(parentIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
            }

        //...
    }
}
```