# Up Button without specific parent

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I have one activity "X" which can be called from multiple activities "A", "B" "C" . 
I'd like to implement the Up Button in the Appbar so that it behaves like the backbutton on a phone.

Meaning:
If one hit the Up button in activity "X" the user should go back to the activity "A" when activity "X" is called from activity "A".
Hope the usecase is clear ;-)

If I try to use the method form that post:

[Multiple Activities and Up Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626598/multiple-activities-and-up-button)

Android Studio tells me, I can't override the onMenuItemSelected method because its final.

Is there away around? Or a better way to do this?

Thanks for any help or hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onMenuItemSelected` is coming up final so I guess you are using `ActionBarActivity`. If yes, try extending `onOptionsItemSelected`. That method isn't final in that class.